# Should I make identical thread groups in JMeter to simulate simultaneous user activity?

Tags: performance, jmeter, load

When doing load testing in JMeter, should I make multiple identical thread groups to simulate multiple users simultaneously performing actions on my site? Or does one thread group with multiple threads/users in it suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread Groups is designed to represent a "group" of virtual users which is "grouped" by some factor.

As per [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) documentation:

> A Thread Group defines a pool of users that will execute a particular test case against your server.

So the answer is `one thread group with multiple threads/users in it suffice`

For example if you are load testing StackOverflow you will have following example groups of users:

1. Not authenticated users searching for answers
2. Authenticated users providing answers
3. Authenticated users asking questions
4. Authenticated users writing comments
5. New users who are signing up

Assuming above setup you will need 5 Thread Groups to represent these 5 different groups of virtual users.

Distribution of users in the same thread group is also possible via [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) or [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller), see [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) guide for more information

Answer (score 0):

we can increase number of thread/users for simulation hence there is no need to add identical threads